# File system becomes (read-only?) on an NVMe SSD seemingly at random

Tags: kubuntu, filesystem, ssd, crash, read-only

I am currently running a somewhat fresh Kubuntu 22.04 install on a relatively new M.2 NVMe drive.

However, I have a problem where my computer drive (I think) turns read only, causing the system to sort of crash. When I first installed the system, this would happen very frequently until I applied the `pcie_aspm=off` fix to the /etc/default/grub file:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off"`. This made it happen less frequently.

This issue happens on all the previous systems I've tried to install on this particular drive, with most of the same symptoms, i.e. some icons disappearing, apps breaking, chromium tabs displaying "aw snap," and also, libreoffice gives a "filesystem read only" error when trying to save a document. One thing I saw that was different from similar errors though, is that when I reboot the computer manually (holding power button) it goes back to normal for a while, while some seem to have problems booting afterwards. Then it happens again some time later. I can provide more details if needed, e.g. hardware, syslog entries, etc.
Does anyone have a permanent solution to this?

Not a computer whiz, but I do know some.
Posted this on the "Unix & Linux" forum, hoping to get more answers by posting it here as well

Here is some system info:

> Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
>
> KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
>
> KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
>
> Qt Version: 5.15.3
>
> Kernel Version: 5.15.0-53-generic (64-bit)
>
> Graphics Platform: X11
>
> Processors: 16 × 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-12600K
>
> Memory: 31.1 GiB of RAM
>
> Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics

Comment: Are you dual booting with Windows? Have you updated UEFI and updated NVMe firmware?

Comment: No, I only run this Kubuntu install on this drive. And also, I didn't update UEFI and NVMe firmware, how do I do that? I thought maybe updating the kernel might help, as I saw that somewhere else.

Comment: What brand/model system. Systems that better support Linux are in fwupdate data base, even if first level help support says they do not support Linux. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist Otherwise you have to go to vendor's site. Both manual & downloads. Most have a download file that UEFI can read directly from a FAT32 formatted partition. SSD may have its own download. My Samsung has a ISO file which I was able to make bootable & update SSD.

Comment: It's a WD black SN850 with heatsink. Since I updated the kernel and BIOS though, I haven't had any serious problems.